# drupal 7 remove logon & password for anonymouse users

Tags: security

I have a username and password for my site for development purposes and now want to take the site live and remove the username and password for anonymous users.  How do I do that?

Comment: How do you mean remove username and password for anonymous users? Are you trying to get rid of the login block? stop them from registering?

Comment: Yes, when you go to the site everyone including anonymous users have to put in a username and password.  I want to remove that block just for anonymous users.

Answer (score 1):

Go to admin/structure/block and look for the user login block set Region dropdown to none. If you are using the default Drupal theme, it would be under sidebar first category

**UPDATE**

but users can still create new accounts from /user page. To disable this, go to

configuration -> people -> account settings -> registration and cancellation and set "Who can register accounts?" -> "Administrators only".

Comment: It is already in the Disabled section of the blocks.

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: Sorry, someone else jumped in and made the fix you described so that did it!  Thanks so much.

Comment: I have updated the answer